Custom fields at registration on Shopify - customer notes or tags?
My plan is to add multiple custom fields (such as a checkbox for marketing consent, input fields) for the registration page on Shopify, and this information should also be stored for each customer (in order to know which user gave consent).
What is the most elegant method to implement this functionality?
The information could be stored in the "customer notes"-field. However, when exporting the customers as an Excel, the entire information will be stored in ONE single column (the customer note one).
Tags might also work, such as "customer_marketing_agree", "customer_marketing_reject". However, again all the information is stored in one column (when opened in Excel).
Are TAGS or CUSTOMER NOTES common and practical to store this type of information or do you have any other suggestions which aren't too complex?
Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
